# Check if a Samba share exists in local network

Tags: linux, samba

i'm trying to figure out how to make a script for check if a dir exist in the network and than backup a directory in the network. Unfortunatly the IP of this machine (Windows 7 with samba) is not static and everytime is changing.

at the moment what I do for backup my notebook is:

in W7 notebook, launch cmq and with ipconfig check the ip of the machine

in linux, go in /etc/hosts file and change the IP set for the notebook
launch rsnapshot manually or wait for the crontab to do it

now what I want to do is a script that does:

to check which IP is available in a range of IPs
check which one has a specific dir available
if both tests are ok, I change the hosts name with the IP and I lanunch the rsnapshot.

maybe a smartest way could be to check if the MAC Address is available in the network and which IP is associated to it and launch the rssnapshot after have changed the hosts or the rsnapshots.conf file

till now what I did is:

for ip in 192.168.1.{128..142}; do  # for loop and the {} operator

```
ping -c 1 -t 1 $ip > /dev/null 2> /dev/null   # ping and discard output
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  # check the exit code
    if [check if dir exists for ip $ip] #not sure how do this check
        /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
else
    echo "${ip} is down"
fi
```

done

Answer (score 0):

Use smbclient to list (-L) the shares ex. :

```
smbclient -L SERVERNAME | grep -i "YOURSHARENAME"
```